# How to assemble needles in Sworksdesign's Espresso WDT tool?

Tags: espresso, equipment, distribution-tool

I just received the [WDT tool from Sworksdesign](https://sworksdesign.com/Aluminum-WDT-Tool-p387817741), which is a tool to fluff up and even out the espresso in the basket before compressing.

However the tool came with next to no assembly instructions.

The body and the needles came separate:

[image]

[image]

and

[image]

Only the following cryptic words were on a leaflet (attached to the needle bag):

> *The middle position will require a kink at the end of the needle handle to stay firmly in place.*
>
> [image]

**How do I install the needles?** Do I have to disassemble the body somehow or do I just push the needles in? Which way? I assume the thicker "wire-wrapped" end goes *into* the body.

Does anybody have experience with this? Thanks heaps for any pointers!

Comment: Welcome to Coffee! I didn't find any assembly video, but I can provide a guess. I think you're on the right track: bend it similarly to how its shown in the picture and then stick the wired end in the holes in the handle. Feel free to self-answer the question if you found that it works that way. If you're really unsure, maybe message the ones who provided the tool?

Comment: @JJJ Thanks. Will self-answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

With [the advice from redditer bigalbundy1827](https://www.reddit.com/r/espresso/comments/xqcwal/comment/iq8xnsl/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I did the following:

Just push needles in every *second* hole plus one needle with the advise bent in the middle channel. Make sure  to put the *wired side* of the needle down in the hole until it reaches the bottom of the channel.

Now it seems to work fine for me: breaking the grind with the WDT tool seems to make the coffee a bit tastier and stronger.